# How to convert IPV6 to 15 chars length integer?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ipv6

I need to convert IPV6 address to 15 chars length integer so I could use IP2LOCATION database?

This is the Database "IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.IPV6.CSV", that I downloaded from here http://download.ip2location.com/lite/

[image]

I try to use this function, but it gives me very long string:

```
function ipv6_numeric($ip) {
   $binNum = '';
   foreach (unpack('C*', inet_pton($ip)) as $byte) {
      $binNum .= str_pad(decbin($byte), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   }
   return base_convert(ltrim($binNum, '0'), 2, 10);
}

ipv6_numeric('fe80:0:0:0:202:b3ff:fe1e:8329')
return "338288524927261046600406220626806860202"
```

Comment: From a cursory look, that's just a partial decimal representation. And there's some more sample code in the docs: https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/importing-ip2location-data-into-couchdb-and-querying-with-php-ipv6/

Comment: If you carry on down the file, there are quite a range of size of numbers (line 186000ish down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this function:

```
function Dot2LongIP($ipv6) {
    return (string) gmp_import(inet_pton($ipv6));
}
```

at this URL: https://lite.ip2location.com/faqs

under the question: "How do I convert an IPv6 Address to an IP Number?"

But your ipv6 address `fe80:0:0:0:202:b3ff:fe1e:8329` also returns a long number: `338288524927261089654163772891438416681`. Note that this result is different from what you have.

As to the length of the result: If you actually look in the CSV file, as suggested by Nigel Ren in a comment, you will see that there are long numbers there as well.

So, this long number is correct.